# Can't add new string instance variable to existing code

Tags: java, string, variables, instance

hi im having problems adding the string instructor name to existing class i made for coursename can you help me fix bugs - this gives me 8 errors

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class GradeBook
{

```
private String courseName, instructorName;

public GradeBook ( String name )
{
    courseName = name; 
}

public GradeBook ( String name )
{
    instructorName = name; 
}

public void setCourseName ( String name )
{
    CourseName = name;
}

public void setInstructorName ( String name )
{
    InstructorName = name;
}

public void getCourseName ( String name )
{
    return courseName;
}

public void getInstructorName ( String name )
{
    return instructorName;
}

public void displayMessage();
{
    System.out.printf( "Welcome to the grade book for\n%s!\n\n",
        getCourseName() );
    System.out.printf( "Your instructor for this course is\n%s!\n\n",
        getCourseName() );
}
```

}

Comment: the class is GradeBook. but it wont let me paste all the code. can you help me with the complete code please, im at my whits end

Comment: Edit your question and add the remaining code.

Comment: here's another piece public GradeBook( String name )
  {
    
    courseName = name;
    
  }
 
  public void setInstructorName( String nameIns )
  {
    
    InstructorName = nameIns;
    
  }
 
  public void setCourseName( String name ) 
  {
    
    courseName = name;
    
  } 
 
  public String getInstructorName()
  {
    
    return instructorName;

Comment: the error is constructor GradeBook(string) is already declared class gradebook. this is only when i add the second string in for insstructor and add the new functions GradeBook( String nameIns ) etc

Answer (score 4):

[From the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.2)

> **It is a compile-time error to declare two constructors with
>   override-equivalent signatures (§8.4.2) in a class.**

and

> Two methods [or constructors] have the same signature if they have the same name and
>   argument types.

In your case, you have two constructors that take one parameter of type `String`. In other words, you have two constructors that have the same signature and the compiler won't allow that.

Either use one constructor that takes two `String` parameters or use setters.

Comment: thanks dude, im really new to this, only on chapter 3. could you possibly show me how to make 1 constructor take 2 strings? then i can complete the program. as the book doesn't cover that. also setters? i added a setCourseName in the code, is that the same?

Comment: @user2850549 [Go through this official tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)

Comment: i dont really want to have to do another tutorial while im doing a tutorial :\ can you just help me without me having to go through all that, otherwise i'll just lose track

Comment: @user Do you know what a method parameter is (or in this case a Constructor parameter)? Just separate them with commas. If your tutorial doesn't show that, it's time to read the one I linked.

Comment: i just need to know how i can use 2 strings in 1 class, as it's same "class gradebook( string) is already declared somewhere

Comment: `public GradeBook( String nameIns, String courseName ) {...}`

Comment: oh wait, you're saying like private String courseName, instructorName; ?

Comment: ok i've edited the main question at the top of the screen's code. this is what i have from what you guys said, but i'm still getting 8 errors... can someone do it for me this once? otherwise i'll never work it out. Thanks just fix the program, then i can review the fixes and know how to do it going forward, this book SUCKS.

Comment: @user2850549 No one is going to do it for _just this once_. Forget your book, read through the tutorial I linked. Understand what the purpose of getters and setters are. Looking at the new code you've posted, you still have two constructors with the same parameter list. That won't do. In some of your methods you are using variables names for variables that aren't declared. Be careful with lowercase/uppercase characters. Java is case sensitive.

Comment: i give up, i've spent 4 hours on this now. i quit, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

```
public GradeBook ( String name )
{
    courseName = name; 
}

public GradeBook ( String name )
{
    instructorName = name; 
}
```

Though you assigned values to 2 different instance variables inside the constructor, for JVM it has same signature. You can't have 2 constructors with same signature.
Either you have to create a constructor that request 2 parameters or assign same values to both instance variables

```
    public GradeBook ( String cName, String iName )
    {
        courseName = cName; 
        instructorName = iName; 
    }
```